# flutter Huawei: push The serviceConnection has been bind for 60s, need to unbind

Tags: android, flutter, dart, huawei-mobile-services

I use the Huawei push plugin to receive the hms notification https://pub.dev/packages/huawei_push
but after a few minutes, The service-connection has been bind in debug console

[image]

then my app can't receive notifications anymore until restart my app to receive notifications again.

I want allow for receive notifications anytime

or

how to unbind service com.huawei.hms.adapter.BinderAdapter

My code is here:

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:huawei_push/huawei_push.dart';
import 'package:signin/features/signin/presentation/page/user_signin_page_view.dart';

class UserSigninPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const UserSigninPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return UserSigninPageState();
  }
}

void backgroundMessageCallback(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) async {
  String? data = remoteMessage.data;
  if (data != null) {
    debugPrint(
      'Background message is received, sending local notification.',
    );
    Push.localNotification(
      <String, String>{
        HMSLocalNotificationAttr.TITLE: '[Headless] DataMessage Received',
        HMSLocalNotificationAttr.MESSAGE: data,
      },
    );
  } else {
    debugPrint(
      'Background message is received. There is no data in the message.',
    );
  }
}

class UserSigninPageState extends State<UserSigninPage> {

  void _onTokenEvent(String event) {
    log("huawei " + event);
  }

  void _onTokenError(Object error) {
    PlatformException e = error as PlatformException;
    print("errorrrrr ${e.message}");
  }

  void _onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    String? data = remoteMessage.data;
    if (data != null) {
      Push.localNotification(
        <String, String>{
          HMSLocalNotificationAttr.TITLE: 'DataMessage Received',
          HMSLocalNotificationAttr.MESSAGE: data,
        },
      );
      log("onMessageReceived: " + data);
    } else {
      log("onMessageReceived: No data is present");
    }
  }

  void _onMessageReceiveError(Object error) {
    PlatformException e = error as PlatformException;
    log("_onMessageReceiveError: " + e.message.toString());
  }

  void _onNotificationOpenedApp(dynamic initialNotification) {
    if (initialNotification != null) {
      print("onNotificationOpenedApp: ${initialNotification.toString()}");
    }
  }

  void _onRemoteMessageSendStatus(String event) {
    log("RemoteMessageSendStatus ${event.toString()}");
  }

  void _onRemoteMessageSendError(Object error) {
    PlatformException e = error as PlatformException;
    log("RemoteMessageSendError" + e.message.toString());
  }

  Future<void> initPlatformStatehms() async {
    if (!mounted) return;
    Push.getTokenStream.listen(_onTokenEvent, onError: _onTokenError);
    Push.onNotificationOpenedApp.listen(_onNotificationOpenedApp);
    dynamic initialNotification = await Push.getInitialNotification();
    _onNotificationOpenedApp(initialNotification);
    Push.onMessageReceivedStream.listen(
      _onMessageReceived,
      onError: _onMessageReceiveError,
    );
    Push.getRemoteMsgSendStatusStream.listen(
      _onRemoteMessageSendStatus,
      onError: _onRemoteMessageSendError,
    );
    bool backgroundMessageHandler = await Push.registerBackgroundMessageHandler(
      backgroundMessageCallback,
    );
    debugPrint(
      'backgroundMessageHandler registered: $backgroundMessageHandler',
    );

    Push.getToken('');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlatformStatehms();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return UserSigninPageView(state: this);
  }
}
```

my debug console

```
I/.example.signi( 6542): Waiting for a blocking GC ProfileSaver
I/flutter ( 6542): rawHandle 3344082687
I/flutter ( 6542): rawCallback 5967833742
I/HmsFlutterPush( 6542): BackgroundMessageHandler registered ✔
W/FlutterJNI( 6542): FlutterJNI.loadLibrary called more than once
I/ResourceExtractor( 6542): Found extracted resources res_timestamp-3-1654501352958
W/FlutterJNI( 6542): FlutterJNI.prefetchDefaultFontManager called more than once
W/FlutterJNI( 6542): FlutterJNI.init called more than once
I/flutter ( 6542): backgroundMessageHandler registered: true
I/FlutterBackgroundRunner( 6542): Starting Background Runner
D/EGL_emulation( 6542): eglCreateContext: 0xf10d0d20: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation( 6542): eglCreateContext: 0xf10d0690: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/HostConnection( 6542): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf10e6030, tid 6624
D/HostConnection( 6542): HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2
D/EGL_emulation( 6542): eglMakeCurrent: 0xf10d0690: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xc1f4f0f0) (first time)
I/HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager( 6542): Enter getHMSPackageNameForMultiService
I/HMSSDK_HMSBIInitializer( 6542): Builder->biInitFlag :false
I/HMSSDK_c( 6542): secretKeyCache not empty.
I/HMSSDK_c( 6542): The local secret is already in separate file mode.
I/HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager( 6542): Enter getHMSPackageNameForMultiService
I/HMSSDK_HMSBIInitializer( 6542): Builder->biInitFlag :false
I/HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager( 6542): Enter getHMSPackageNameForMultiService
I/HMSSDK_HuaweiApi( 6542): No setInnerHms, hms pkg name is com.huawei.hwid
I/HMSSDK_HuaweiApi( 6542): sendRequest
I/HMSSDK_HuaweiApi( 6542): isConnected:true.
I/HMSSDK_BaseHmsClient( 6542): getAdapter:isInner:false, mInnerBinderAdapter:null, mOuterBinderAdapter:com.huawei.hms.adapter.BinderAdapter@8dde06
I/HMSSDK_RequestManager( 6542): addToConnectedReqMap
I/HMSSDK_HmsClient( 6542): post msg api_name:push.gettoken, app_id:106360485|, pkg_name:com.example.signin, sdk_version:60400302, session_id:*, transaction_id:106360485ttoken20220606144242589563301, kitSdkVersion:60300304, apiLevel:1
I/HMSSDK_HmsClient( 6542): Activity is null for 106360485
I/HMSSDK_BaseAdapter( 6542): In constructor, WeakReference is java.lang.ref.WeakReference@9cb6d9d
I/HMSSDK_BaseAdapter( 6542): in baseRequest + uri is :push.gettoken, transactionId is : 106360485ttoken20220606144242589563301
I/HMSSDK_PendingResultImpl( 6542): init uri:push.gettoken
I/HMSSDK_PendingResultImpl( 6542): setResultCallback
I/HMSSDK_PendingResultImpl( 6542): setResult:0
I/HMSSDK_BaseAdapter( 6542): api is: push.gettoken, resolution: null, status_code: 0
I/HMSSDK_BaseAdapter( 6542): baseCallBack.onComplete
I/HMSSDK_HmsClient( 6542): receive msg status_code:0, error_code:0, api_name:push.gettoken, app_id:106360485|, pkg_name:com.example.signin, session_id:*, transaction_id:106360485ttoken20220606144242589563301, resolution:null
I/HMSSDK_TaskApiCall( 6542): doExecute, uri:push.gettoken, errorCode:0, transactionId:106360485ttoken20220606144242589563301
I/SecurityComp10105310: BaseKeyUtil( 6542): exportRootKey: sha256
I/HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager( 6542): Enter getHMSPackageNameForMultiService
I/HMSSDK_RequestManager( 6542): removeReqByTransId
D/HMSLogger( 6542): singleEventMap -> {apiName=getToken, package=com.example.signin, cpAppVersion=1.0.0, version=6.1.0.300, platform=Flutter, result=0, costTime=781, service=Cross-Platform, kit=Push, appid=106360485, model=generic_x86, networkType=WIFI, callTime=1654501363212}
[log] huawei ANE222536T5waBD-Ni5yP5mUE6KobsiaAUZrL-DK4kxNNoK3B4aSlXniqpt_htE0JwOY2npUPGLjVnaSSSkrC45b5rovK-YAMFx2Ia8xCnfmq2XCBuD50h1FJCs7KaNHuQ
I/HMSSDK_BinderAdapter( 6542): The serviceConnection has been bind for 60s, need to unbind.
I/HMSSDK_Util( 6542): Trying to unbind service from com.huawei.hms.adapter.BinderAdapter@8dde06
```

Comment: Can you provide detailed log information about messages that cannot be received?

Answer (score -1):

Even though we can unbind the service but to track down the root cause, please provide more log info. and let me know: Phone model， EMUI version， the HMS Core (APK) version, HMS SDK version.

some reference steps for push log:

1）Connect the adb tool to your device and run the following commands:

adb shell setprop log.tag.hwpush VERBOSE

adb logcat -v threadtime 1> D:\hwpush.log

2）Reproduce the problem scenario.

3）Press Ctrl+C to complete log capture.

Thanks